# How to make html5 full screen in Libgdx?

Tags: html, gwt, browser, libgdx

Does anyone know how to set the canvas full screen in HTML5 LibGDX?

I only find width and height property in `GwtApplicationConfiguration`.

Comment: Added the GWT tag since this is probably as much a GWT question as a Libgdx one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a Stage so I had to use an InputMultiplexer to send input to both my Stage and the InputAdapter that handles fullscreen GWT requests.

```
    InputAdapter webGlfullscreen = new InputAdapter() {
        @Override
        public boolean keyUp (int keycode) {
            if (keycode == Keys.ENTER && Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.WebGL) {
                if (!Gdx.graphics.isFullscreen()) Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode(Gdx.graphics.getDisplayModes()[0]);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputMultiplexer(webGlfullscreen, stage));
```

Comment: Is it possible to produce this full screen "pop-out" perspective immediately after the initial load (as opposed to having the client trigger full screen mode on key press)? Simply putting 'Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode(Gdx.graphics.getDisplayModes()[0]);' in a show() method yields a "flattened", non "pop-outish" perspective that isn't what you'd expect for a genuine full screen setting.